# Set view height base on device width in constraintlayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

this is my code and its output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5"
    android:layout_marginStart="68dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

now viewpager width is 50% of device width and viewpager height is 50% of device height but I want to set viewpager height base on device width (50% of device width), is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ratio constraint attribute of the ConstraintLayout :

Add this line in the layout to have height equal to width :

```
app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
```

And Remove this line :

```
app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5"  //remove this
```

This will form a perfect square view with equal width and height.

Have a look : [ConstraintLayout | Ratio](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout?hl=id#ratio)